# Get list of all Point3D in Viewport3D in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, viewport3d

Is there a simple method to return a list of all Point3D present in a Viewport3D object in WPF? I need this collection in order to determine the XYZ bounds so that I can position the camera such that all Point3D are within the field of view.

If there is no simple method, which collections would I need to iterate over to ensure all Point3D are captured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very lengthy hierarchy we need to traverse to get to the data you want.

- `Viewport3D.Children` returns a `Visual3DCollection` object which contains a set of `Visual3D`
- `Visual3D` has 3 child classes; we are interested in `ModelVisual3D`
- `ModelVisual3D.Children` returns another `Visual3DCollection`; you can clearly see the recursive tree structure with `Viewport3D` at the root
- `ModelVisual3D.Visual3DModel` returns a `Model3D` object
- `Model3D` has 3 child classes; we are interested in `GeometryModel3D` and `Model3DGroup`
- `Model3DGroup.Children` is another list of `Model3D`; hence we have two layers of recursive containment
- `GeometryModel3D.Geometry` returns a `Geometry3D` object
- Curiously, `Geometry3D` only has one child class `MeshGeometry3D`
- `MeshGeometry3D.Positions` finally gives a raw list of points

---

Note that these points are in the *local* bases of their parent `Geometry3D` objects. In order to get the world coordinates, as you traverse the hierarchy you must accumulate a list of the transformations of any `Model3D` objects you encounter, and use them to transform the output points.

- `Model3D.Transform` returns a `Transform3D` object
- `Transform3D` has 3 child classes - `AffineTransform3D`, `MatrixTransform3D` and `Transform3DGroup`; however we won't need to deal with them separately
- `Transform3D.Transform(Point3D)` is pretty self explanatory
- I don't see a multiplication operator between two `Transform3D` classes (except `MatrixTransform3D`), so for each `Point3D` you must traverse the list of transformations *in reverse order* and apply each transformation in succession

---

The above summarizes why almost no one uses WPF for 3D development... a discussion which should be reserved for [linux.stackexchange.com](http://linux.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I needed a summary of all the nesting in this unholy mess of a hierarchy and your answer is actually a solid reference.

Comment: @bokibeg likewise, "unholy mess" is a solid description.